# Implementation of priority queue using linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, queue

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//template<class T>
class Node
{
    public:
//  T data;
    int data;
    Node *next;
    int priority;
};

//template<class T>
class Que
{
        Node *front , *rear;
    public:
        Que(){front = rear = NULL;}

//      void enqueue(T x);
//      T dequeue();
        void enqueue(int *x, int l);
        int dequeue();
        void display();
};

//template<class T>
//void Que<T>::enqueue(T x)
void Que::enqueue(int *x, int l)
{
    Node * pt = front;
    for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
    Node *t = NULL;
    t = new Node;
    if(t==NULL)
        cout<<"Queue is full"<<endl;
    else
    {
        t->next = NULL;
        t->data = x[i];
        t->priority = x[i];
        if(front==NULL)
            front = rear =t;
        else
        {
            if(front->priority <= t->priority)
            {
                t->next = front;
                front = t;
            }
            else
            {
                while(pt->next!= NULL && pt->next->priority <= x[i])
                    pt = pt->next;
                t->next = pt->next;
                pt->next = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

//template<class T>
//T Que<T>::dequeue()
int Que::dequeue()
{
//  T x = -1;
    int x = -1;
    Node *t = NULL;
    if(front == NULL)
        cout<<"Queue is empty"<<endl;
    else
    { 
        x = front->data;
        t = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete t;
    }
    return x;
}

//template<class T>
//void Que<T>::display()
void Que::display()
{
    Node *t = front;
    while(t)
    {
        cout<<t->data<<" ";
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
//  Que <int> q();
    Que q;
    int a [] = {6, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3};
    q.enqueue(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
//  q.dequeue();
    q.display();
    return 0;
}
```

It's a code for priority queue using linked list in C++. The while loop inside enqueue member function is showing segmentation fault.

I think pointer `*pt` to node which is used to point front is not pointing correctly. I have been trying to resolve it but couldn't get any idea. What can be reason for it?

Comment: time to debug your own code

Comment: If you separate the priority queue from the linked list--build the priority queue around the linked list rather than inside the linked list--you can test and debug smaller, less complicated chunks of code at a time.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular the part about describing the problem before you dump code on us.

Comment: The best way to debug problems like this is to single-step the code in your debugger. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It will save you countless hours of debugging time. Also, the advice to build the priority queue around the linked list is a good one.

Comment: In addition to using the debugger, draw pictures. Nothing helps you understand a graphing problem, even a simple graph like a linked list, like visualizing it. Draw the list. Draw all of the steps you need to perform in order to perform the desired operation on the list. Follow along in the the drawings while debugging. When you see the program doing something other than what you drew, you found a bug AND you probably have a good idea what to do instead.

Comment: Maybe your teacher also use this website.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `pt` at the start of `enqueue` but never reset it within the loop.  So when you add multiple elements to an empty list, `pt` will start as `nullptr`, and won't be updated after the first element is added to the list.  When you try to add the second element to the list you dereference `pt->next` which cause your segmentation fault because `pt` is still `nullptr`.

The fix is easy: move `Node * pt = front;` to *within* the for loop.